# How to correctly build RegEx for multiline values in reg file

Tags: regex, powershell, registry

I would like to get values from a .reg file (REG EXPORT file) so I can compare them to another .reg file. I'm having problems to create the RegEx for this.

facts which make it harder for me:

1. I don't know what kind of registry key types are being used in the file (that's why I want to build a regex for all the different types like string, dword, qword, multistring,...)
2. I don't know if the last character in the file is a newline or not
3. I would like to only return the actual value, e.g. `fa,ad,df,fa,ad,df,fa,ad` if the regkey is `"qword"=hex(b):fa,ad,df,fa,ad,df,fa,ad`

```bsh
$Text = @'
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test]
"String"="asfasdfasasfasdfasasfasdfasasfas"
"Binary"=hex:d3,45,34,53,45,34,53,45,34,53,45,34,53,45,34,53,45,34,5b,09,89,08,\
34,09,8a,ef,02,30,40,9a,ad,fa,d0
"DWORD"=dword:fefefefe
"multistring"=hex(7):61,00,62,00,6c,00,61,00,73,00,66,00,62,00,00,00,62,00,61,\
  00,6c,00,73,00,66,00,62,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,66,00,00,00,62,00,61,00,6c,00,\
  73,00,64,00,66,00,61,00,64,00,6c,00,66,00,00,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,66,00,61,\
  00,73,00,64,00,66,00,00,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,66,00,00,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,\
  00,00,66,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,00,00,66,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,66,00,61,00,73,\
  00,66,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,66,00,00,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,66,00,61,00,73,00,\
  64,00,66,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,00,00,61,00,73,00,64,00,66,00,61,00,73,00,64,\
  00,66,00,00,00,00,00
"qword"=hex(b):fa,ad,df,fa,ad,df,fa,ad
'@

# this one works
$key = "multistring"
$regex = ('(?ms)\"{0}\"=hex\(7\):(.+)\n' -f [RegEx]::Escape($key))
[regex]::Matches($Text, $regex) | foreach { $_.Groups[1].Value }

# this one does not work because there is no newline after the last line...
$key2 = "qword"
$regex2 = ('(?ms)\"{0}\"=hex\(b\):(.+)\n' -f [RegEx]::Escape($key2))
[regex]::Matches($Text, $regex2) | foreach { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Comment: You can make the trailing newline optional `\n?` or try `(\n|$)`

Comment: You could easily add newline to the end of the data.

Comment: If I try to make the newline optional with @marekful's examples, the returned value always contains all characters until the end of the file, which means all following keys get returned as well (if it is not the last registry key in the file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex you use `(?s)` which is a [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html) that will make the dot match any character including new lines. So `.+` will match until the end of all lines.

You could use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to capture the part after the colon.
First match the part uptil a colon using `\"{0}\"=hex\(7\):`

Then match what follows until the end of the line and use a negative lookahead to check if what follows is not a line that starts with a word between double quotes followed by an equals sign like "qword"=. As long as that is the case, match the whole string.

Your code could look like:

```
$regex = \"{0}\"=hex\(7\):(.*(?:(?!\n"[^\n"]+"=)\n.*)*)
```

Explanation of the second part:

- `(` Capturing group which will hold your value

  - `.*` Match any character except a newline 0+ times
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!` Negative lookahead to assert what follows is not

      - `\n"[^\n"]+"=` Match `\n"`, negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match not any of `\n` or `"`
    - `)\n.*` Close negative lookahead and match `\n` followed by any character except a newline 0+ times
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close capturing group

Example Pattern

```
\"multistring\"=hex\(7\):(.*(?:(?!\n"[^\n"]+"=)\n.*)*)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%22multistring%5c%22%3dhex%5c%287%5c%29%3a%28.*%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5cn%22%5b%5e%5cn%22%5d%2b%22%3d%29%5cn.*%29*%29&i=%5bHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE%5cSOFTWARE%5cTest%5d%0d%0a%22String%22%3d%22asfasdfasasfasdfasasfasdfasasfas%22%0d%0a%22Binary%22%3dhex%3ad3%2c45%2c34%2c53%2c45%2c34%2c53%2c45%2c34%2c53%2c45%2c34%2c53%2c45%2c34%2c53%2c45%2c34%2c5b%2c09%2c89%2c08%2c%5c%0d%0a34%2c09%2c8a%2cef%2c02%2c30%2c40%2c9a%2cad%2cfa%2cd0%0d%0a%22DWORD%22%3ddword%3afefefefe%0d%0a%22multistring%22%3dhex%287%29%3a61%2c00%2c62%2c00%2c6c%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c62%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c62%2c00%2c61%2c%5c%0d%0a++00%2c6c%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c62%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c62%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c6c%2c00%2c%5c%0d%0a++73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c6c%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c%5c%0d%0a++00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c%5c%0d%0a++00%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c%5c%0d%0a++00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c%5c%0d%0a++64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c00%2c66%2c00%2c61%2c00%2c73%2c00%2c64%2c%5c%0d%0a++00%2c66%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c00%2c00%0d%0a%22qword%22%3dhex%28b%29%3afa%2cad%2cdf%2cfa%2cad%2cdf%2cfa%2cad%0d%0a)

Answer (score 1):

`.+` is a greedy expression, and the modifier `(?s)` makes the `.` match *all* characters (including newlines), so `(.+)\n` will match everything up to the last newline.

Try something like this:

```
$regex = '"{0}"=hex\(b\):(.+(?:\n  .+)*)'
```

You need neither `(?m)` nor `(?s)` here, because you don't want `.` to include newlines, and you don't want to match beginnings or ends of lines inside the multiline string. `.+(?:\n  .+)*` matches the rest of the line after the prefix `hex(b):` and all subsequent lines beginning with two consecutive spaces. The `(?:...)` is just a non-capturing group, since there's no need to capture each line in a separate group.

Comment: thank you also very much, your solution works perfectly as well! :)